# How to let current bootstrap tab to remain active?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

May I know how to maintain currect bootstrap tab (id="liProcessin") active after reload?

I am unable to do it via:

```
               $('.btn-save-all').click(function () {

                   $("input[name*='txtid']").each(function () {
                       let id = $(this).attr('name');
                       id = id.replace('txtid', '');
                       let dat = $(this).val();

                       SaveExpectedBookDate(id, dat);

                   });
                     alert("Success");
                     window.location.reload();
                  /* $('#profile-tab').attr('class', 'active in');*/
                  $('#liProcess-in').addClass('active in');


               });

    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs bar_tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active in"><a href="#tab_content1" id="home-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">All My Requests</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="" id="liProcessin"><a href="#tab_content2" role="tab" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">In-Process</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#liProcess-in').addClass('active in');
});
```

maybe you can add in your js like that